# sed multiline skip lines with N option

Tags: bash, sed, multiline

I use SED with N option for three strings and he misses last string.
If an even number of rows then everything works fine

Example text:

```
this is the first line   
this is the second line
this is the third line

sed 'N;s/^.*\(first.*\)\n\(second.*$\)/\1\2/;s/ //g'
```

I want to get

> thisisthefirstline**thisisthesecondline**
>   thethirdline

but I get

> thisisthefirstline**thisisthesecondline**
>   *the third line*

the last line is not processed, 
sed skips this subscript

```
s/ //g
```

for four lines okay

```
this is the first line   
this is the second line
this is the third line
this is the fourth line

thisisthefirstline**thisisthesecondline**
thisisthethirdline
thisisthefourthline
```

for an odd number of lines is not always processed last row

a simple solution - use a pipe

```
sed 'N;s/^.*\(first.*\)\n\(second.*$\)/\1\2/' | sed 's/ //g'
```

but I would do it without pipe

Answer (score 1):

Because sed sees at the end that it can't N for you so it doesn't process  it, just put without N on the last line like:

`sed '$!N;s/^.*\(first.*\)\n\(second.*$\)/\1\2/;s/ //g'`

The $ means last line, and the ! means not - so $!N means N except on the last line.

Also I presumed you wanted the answer to the N question but really you don't need N for what you are doing, it would suffice to do:

`sed 's/^.*\(first.*\)\n\(second.*$\)/\1\2/;s/ //g'`